# SSL configuration for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to configure ssl for my asp.net core app. I use IIS as reverse proxy and I can't understand where I need to configure SSL.

I have found this article recently:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/29/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/
There all configurations are made in c# code.

But in internet I also saw articles where configuration was in IIS and web.config.

Which way is more correct?

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad, but as you're using IIS as a reverse proxy, you can configure SSL in IIS itself or using a `Web.config` as you suggest. The article you linked is specific to hosting using Kestrel *directly*.

Comment: If you're using a reverse proxy like IIS, then SSL should be configured there.

Comment: Learn the context. If you just need server side SSL, configuring IIS (or other reverse proxy) would be enough. If you need mutual SSL, then there would be more settings.